# java convert String of integers into possible combination of ASCII characters

Tags: java, string, char, ascii

Say that I have

```
    String input = "Programming", result="\0";
    int temp;
    for (int i=0;i<input.length();++i) {
        temp = input.charAt(i);
        result += temp;
    }
```

`result` would be `8011411110311497109109105110103`. I know that

```
    P = 80
    r = 114
    o = 111
    g = 103
    r = 114
    a = 97
    m = 109
    m = 109
    i = 105
    n = 110
    g = 103
```

Out of curiosity, is it possible, in easy way, to reverse the process?

Comment: Say you had `123`. Should it be `12` + `3` or `1` + `23`?

Comment: I don't think you can, as it will be hard to differentiate whether 2 numbers is one char or 3 numbers: p was `80`, but g is `103`. So, you don't know whether to expect 2 digits/char or 3 digits/char

Comment: That's why I asked if it is possible, in easy way, to do that since even a short String creates so many possibilities.

Comment: You would have to generate it with all 3 digits so 80 would be 080 or as hex (then all would be 2 chars) then you could reverse it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you would have to do is assume that Each number lies between either 'A' to 'Z', (65 to 90) or 'a' to 'z' (97 to 122)

1. get the first 2 digits via a call to `substring()`
2. check if those lie within the above bounds by converting to a numeric type

   - if they do then continue with the loop
3. else get the third digit and check that

it would be much simpler if you could have it be padded to three digits so you would know that every three digits formed an ASCII letter

code that works only if it is letters:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     String toConvert= "8011411110311497109109105110103";
     String result="";
     while(toConvert.length()>0){
         String digits=toConvert.substring(0, 2);
         int num=Integer.valueOf(digits);
         if(('A'<=num&&num<='Z')||('a'<=num&&num<='z')){
             toConvert=toConvert.substring(2);
         }
         else{
             digits=toConvert.substring(0, 3);
             num=Integer.valueOf(digits);
             toConvert=toConvert.substring(3);
         }
         String letter = String.valueOf((char) num);
         result+=letter;
     }
     System.out.println(result);
}
```

**note** if you change the test to `num>25` , then it will correctly work for all ASCII values from 26 up: for values 26 to 99, it will interpret them as having 2 digits correctly, for values from 100 to 255 it will only look at the first 2 digits, so they will be seen as 10-25, and will be interpreted as 3 digits long